# how to implement soap request in php?

Tags: php, soap

I searched this website for a helpful response for integrating a SOAP Request in PHP, but I didn't find anything that solved my problem.

I'm new to SOAP and can't figure out why I am not getting any response:

```
 <?php
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'.
    ' xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"'.
    ' xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'.
        '<soap:Body>'.
            '<food xmlns="http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/xml1.xml">'.
                '<price>$5.95</price>'.
            '</food>'.
        '</soap:Body>'.
    '</soap:Envelope>';

$url = "http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/xml1.xml";

$ch = curl_init();
echo $ch;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$headers = array();
array_push($headers, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
array_push($headers, "Accept: text/xml");
array_push($headers, "Cache-Control: no-cache");
array_push($headers, "Pragma: no-cache");
array_push($headers, "SOAPAction:http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/xml1.xml");
if($xml != null) {
    echo $xml;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml");
    array_push($headers, "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml));
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user_name:password"); /* If required */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo"<br/> CODE:"$code;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: There is an error in `echo"<br/> CODE:"$code;` which is missing a full stop - `echo"<br/> CODE:".$code;`

Comment: And you can just use  `echo"<br/> CODE: $code"; `code` aswell. I just created a class for SOAP call similar to yours few days ago at work, so what's your  `var_dump($response) ` saying, nothing?

Comment: Just use the SoapClient library

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing URL from curl_init which will initialize a cURL session, but yours has no URL.

```
    $curl = curl_init("http://www.localhost:81/dbWIP/xml1.xml");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

And try setting your headers to

```
   $headers = array(
        'Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"',
        'Accept: text/xml',
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Pragma: no-cache',
        'Content-length: ' . strlen($xml),
    );
```

Comment: the url is set with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the quotation marks:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
```